# Implement Web Login from Native iOS App

Tags: ios, web-services, security, mobile

We have an app that has a backend web service. We are looking to implement a user authentication from our native iOS app to the web server. We want our native app to login to the website, get a token to use for requests and expire this token after a period of time (e.g., after 30 days).

We are looking for sample code to show how to do this for a native iOS app.

For example, do we use a UIWebView with the web login url? An advantage of this is that the user registration, forgotten passwords, etc. code for the web is available to the native app. Otherwise, we would have to re-write the registration, account confirmation, forgotten password code for the native app. If we use the web view approach, what do we save in the native app to verify requests from logged in users?

If we re-implement the registration, verification, forgotten password, login code for the native app, what are the things we need to worry about? What is the best way to implement this code? A sample pseudo or real code is appreciated.

Comment: What's the point in making a native app at all if you're going to use web views to save you reimplementing parts of it? Just create the native screens  to register, login and retrieve password. I doubt you'd be able to access authentication cookies/headers from the http responses within a web view anyway. Btw you've tagged Android which is why I came across this, can't help with code.

Comment: The native app gives the advantages of a native app (e.g., responsive, available offline for a while, consistent with other native app, etc). The server has information useful/relevant to the logged in user that needs to be synched with the local data.

Answer (score 0):

My coworker and I just implemented a web view for login into an enterprise app we are building. You have listed many good reasons for this approach, and it works.

I am not an expert in this area, but I will describe what we accomplished in a matter of several days. Hope it helps.

First, the web login page we display is an existing enterprise login system that supports the OAuth2 protocol. OAuth2 is a pretty popular and secure  way to support this type of authentication. There is a ton of information about OAuth2 on the web, and it's fairly complicated, in my opinion. The first key to making us successful was having this enterprise login system already available with OAuth2 support. We didn't write any backend code.

Second, we used this open source library to handle the implementation of the OAuth2 protocol in iOS: https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client

As I mentioned, OAuth2 is complicated to implement. The library takes care of most of the complexity, so the amount of code we had to write was small.

Using the library was a bit challenging, but we managed. The library documentation will get you started, but we found this tutorial extremely helpful in getting it all working:
http://www.idmworks.com/blog/entry/getting-started-with-oauth2client-on-ios

Our solution involves a single login view controller which hosts the web view, and a class to manage the keys and URLs needed to configure the library.

With this approach, authentication is handled entirely by the web view. Upon successful authentication, our view controller intercepts the redirect URL and uses the request token it provides to obtain an access token that can be used to access secure resources. The heavy lifting here is handled by library, and our enterprise login system. Our app has relatively little to do. The library stores the tokens securely in the keychain. It also supports a refresh token which allows for silently refreshing the access token, if your backend supports that.

When our app launches, it navigates to the login view controller if the user is not signed in, or to the main view controller if user is signed in.